# Why does `(\x y -> x + y) @Integer` fails, but `(+) @Integer` succeeds?

Tags: haskell, types

Consider:

```
λ :type (+) @Integer
(+) @Integer :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer




λ :type (\x y -> x + y) @Integer
...
...error...
...Cannot apply expression...
...

λ f = (+)
λ :type f @Integer
...
...error...
...Cannot apply expression...
...

λ g = \x y -> x + y
λ :type g @Integer
...
...error...
...Cannot apply expression...
...

λ h x y = x + y
λ :type h @Integer
...
...error...
...Cannot apply expression...
...
```

At the same time:

```
λ :type (+)
... :: Num a => a -> a -> a

λ :type (\x y -> x + y)
... :: Num a => a -> a -> a

λ :type f
... :: Num a => a -> a -> a

λ :type g
... :: Num a => a -> a -> a

λ :type h
... :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So, even though there is no distinction in the type of these objects, they appear as distinct to the type application.

- Why?
- Am I missing something obvious?
- Is this a bug?
- Is this a feature?
- Is this poor language design?
- Is this great language design?

Comment: In a basic Hindley-Milner system, types are generalized only by `let` (i.e. definitions). That would include, roughly, `f,g,h` but not anonymous lambdas. So, one could expect that `@ T` did not work on non-generalized bindings. With the Monomorphism Restriction, `f,g` would also not be generalized, and only `h` would work. Haskell apparently does something even different, since even `h` fails to work. It's puzzling that adding a type annotation to `h` with the same inferred type makes it work in `h @ T`.

Comment: You say there is no distinction in the type of these objects, but you are not quite correct -- GHC does track a difference between them. In ghci, try `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls`, then `:type +v (+)` and `:type +v (\x y -> x + y)`: you will see that one wraps its type variable in braces and one doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases type applications can only be applied when there is an explicit type signature.  Quoting the GHC documents:

> If the function is an identifier (the common case), its type is considered known only when the identifier has been given a type signature.
>
> Why?

I'd guess that design exists because the order of type variables is well defined when you have explicit signatures.

> Am I missing something obvious?

Up to you how obvious the above is.  You can dig thought both the docs and the design discussion to see the evolution of the conversation but order of arguments, when type application can only be done strictly by the order, seems to jump out as an issue.

> Is this a bug?

I don't believe so. Perhaps for the lambda case.

> Is this a feature?

A feature in so far as consistency is good.

> Is this poor language design?
> Is this great language design?

Perhaps a better language design is to allow simple examples, such as yours, to work when there are no possible ambiguities (the type argument order is implicit by virtue of there only being one type argument).